# App crashing on google map load with error "libc.so abort 160 flutter"

Tags: android, flutter, google-maps

App crashing on google map load with error "libc.so abort 160 flutter" on android devices.

**release apk only debug is working well !!**

there is no detailed errors i don't know what problem is..
[image]

**edit**
I found the error !!

2020-11-11 20:44:58.995 25431-25431/? E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views: Failed to handle method call java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.Map.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference at io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.e.s(Unknown Source:10) at io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.g.a(Unknown Source:28) at io.flutter.plugin.platform.SingleViewPresentation.onCreate(Unknown Source:116) at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:423) at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:317) at android.app.Presentation.show(Presentation.java:259) at io.flutter.plugin.platform.l.(Unknown Source:55) at io.flutter.plugin.platform.l.a(Unknown Source:65) at io.flutter.plugin.platform.k$a.g(Unknown Source:110) at io.flutter.embedding.engine.i.i$a.b(Unknown Source:152) at io.flutter.embedding.engine.i.i$a.G(Unknown Source:144) at g.a.d.a.j$a.a(Unknown Source:17) at io.flutter.embedding.engine.e.b.d(Unknown Source:57) at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(Unknown Source:4) at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method) at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:182) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7564) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950) 2020-11-11 20:44:58.997 25431-25491/? E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.Map.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference, null, java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.Map.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference at io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.e.s(Unknown Source:10) at io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.g.a(Unknown Source:28) at io.flutter.plugin.platform.SingleViewPresentation.onCreate(Unknown Source:116) at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:423) at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:317) at android.app.Presentation.show(Presentation.java:259) at io.flutter.plugin.platform.l.(Unknown Source:55) at io.flutter.plugin.platform.l.a(Unknown Source:65) at io.flutter.plugin.platform.k$a.g(Unknown Source:110) at io.flutter.embedding.engine.i.i$a.b(Unknown Source:152) at io.flutter.embedding.engine.i.i$a.G(Unknown Source:144) at g.a.d.a.j$a.a(Unknown Source:17) at io.flutter.embedding.engine.e.b.d(Unknown Source:57) at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(Unknown Source:4) at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method) at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:182) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7564) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950) ) #0 StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:582) #1 MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:159)  #2 TextureAndroidViewController._sendCreateMessage (package:flutter/src/services/platform_views.dart:1039)  #3 AndroidViewController.create (package:flutter/src/services/platform_views.dart:749)  #4 RenderAndroidView._sizePlatformView (package:flutter/src/rendering/platform_view.dart:174)

Comment: You don't happen to be using a ListView are you?

Comment: no i don't use listview

Comment: if a remove google map from page its working well.. so i think google maps causing this

Comment: Yeah. This appears to be a problem with a keyboard opening over top of a ListView/something that can scroll (including google maps).... https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/45218

Comment: Any difference between linking of libraries in Debug and Release mode ?

Comment: i'm ot sure what are you asking about but i think both using same libraries

Comment: manually i didnot splitted libraries for debug and release

Comment: I found error and updated question please check.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED.

Looks like gradle update ruined project.. some classes was missing in release build.
I Downgraded gadle to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2'
```

and its working now